# How to find the top 5 values using max() in sql

Tags: sql

I want the top 5 products from a table

If i use this

```
SELECT MAX(ProductCode) AS ProductName 
FROM OrderDetails
```

I get only one result I want the top 5 result

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a definition of what "most ordered" means.  I have removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: tag you dbms name

Comment: I don't understand how a column named "ProductCode" is any indication on how often that product was ordered.

Comment: Perhaps it should be top 5 ordered by `count(distinct productCode)`, but without more information, any attempt to answer this question is nothing but a guess.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved..by using this query

> SELECT TOP 5 ProductName, COUNT(ProductName) AS value_occurrence FROM OrderDetails GROUP BY ProductName ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC

Answer (score 2):

Try this for MySQl

```
SELECT ProductCode FROM OrderDetails
ORDER BY ProductCode Desc 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: my product code is varchar by using this query may i get the exact reult that i want?

Comment: in this query you seperated OrderDetails by a space, so i joined them

Comment: its not what i wanted.. from my table i want to figure out the top 5 products that orderd by the customers..

its orderdetail table its contain products orderd by diffrent customers only i can figure out by the largest product from the list by its count

Comment: I gave you solution according to your question. But you are asking something else, However I still couldn't undestand what you need. Please provider sample data and expected output.